# How to get opt-in link after Beta roll out (google play)

Tags: android, google-play-console

I have rolled out the first version of the application to the Beta testers.But i am unable to find the link for APK.

SC:-[image: Screen Shot]

Comment: is it release approved by play store ?

Comment: It's BETA release.How can i check?

Comment: You would get a notification on play store that your update is live , the first release can take any where from 1 day to 7 days . The opt in url should be like 

`https://play.google.com/apps/testing/your.package.name`  .

Answer (score 0):

For many developers, it's just a matter of time. Rolling out merely gets you to the Pending publication stage. After some time you reach the Published stage and the URL will appear.

[image]